# Creating JAXB classes for a complex schema

Tags: import, jaxb, xsd, xjc

I have a complex schema that imports two other schemas.I would like to generate JAXB classes from the same complex schema. I tried in both IDE and command line. But I'm not able to generate the classes.

```
 parsing a schema...
```

[ERROR] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'act:Activity' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 22 of file:/C:/Program%20Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/bin/Request.xsd

I get the above error through command line.

Any idea how to generate the classes from this schema. Does XJC supports imports?

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB's XJC utility definitely supports import and include.  The first thing to check is that the imported/included files contain a valid system ID that can be resolved.  If they don't you can leverage a schema catalog so that XJC can find the secondary XML Schemas.

**Schema Catalog - TR9401 Format**

```
-- Match address.xsd by URL --
SYSTEM "http://www.example.com/address/address.xsd" "imports/address.xsd"

-- Match phone-number.xsd by namespace URI --
PUBLIC "http://www.example.com/phone-number" "imports/phone-number.xsd"
```

**Schema Catlog - OASIS XML Catalog Format**

```
<!DOCTYPE catalog
    PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
           "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">

    <system
        systemId="http://www.example.com/address/address.xsd"
        uri="imports/address.xsd"/>
    <public
        publicId="http://www.example.com/phone-number"
        uri="imports/phone-number.xsd"/>

</catalog>
```

**XJC Call**

The schema catalog is referenced using the `-catalog` flag.

```
xjc -d out -catalog catalog.cat customer.xsd
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/10/jaxb-xjc-imported-schemas-and-xml.html